# CAKeyframeAnimation - Examples

Tags: iphone, animation, uikit, core-animation, calayer

I have a a menu that is a CALayer that will slide across the screen to a given point.  I want the effect where the menu will go a little past the point, then a little before the point, and then land on the point.  I can move the menu by applying a transform, but I was hoping to get this bouncing effect to work.  I was looking into CAKeyframeAnimation, but I'm having trouble locating an example/tutorial.  I've looked at the CA Programming Guide but haven't really found anything.  Any links or help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161465/how-to-create-custom-easing-function-with-core-animation . The first answer there might give you some ideas.

Comment: Checkout this framework I built that does some wicked stuff :) Should be a fairly good abstraction, as it does a lot under the hood https://github.com/AntonTheDev/FlightAnimator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I released [some code](http://ftutils.com) a while ago that does just what you're looking for. Basically, you need to generate your own `CGPathRef` containing all of the points you want the layer to hit, and use that path for the `path` attribute of the `CAKeyframeAnimation`. The code will look something like this:

```
CGPoint path[3] = {
    FTAnimationOutOfViewCenterPoint(enclosingView.bounds, view.frame, view.center, direction),
    [self overshootPointFor:view.center withDirection:direction threshold:(overshootThreshold_ * 1.15)],
    view.center
};

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
CGMutablePathRef thePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddLines(thePath, NULL, path, 3);
animation.path = thePath;
CGPathRelease(thePath);
```

The whole method is [here](https://github.com/neror/ftutils/blob/master/Classes/FTAnimationManager.m#L333).